# Wireless headset(bluetooth) connect with more than one device simultaneously

Tags: audio, connection, bluetooth

There are **two devices** notebook and android phone that both **come with bluetooth**, is it possible to **connect them together with one bluetooth headset at a time**? That means I can **listen both sides of sound** that from the notebook and the smartphone, **no need to switch** connection between them..

I heard something about **multipoint** of bluetooth but not clearly, anyone can help with this question? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the devices using Multipoint bluetooth that you are talking about:

https://jawbone.com/headsets/icon/overview

But the catch is - You cannot listen from 2 sources at the same time, you can switch from one source to another.

Comment: Is that means i have to buy an headset support multipoint and one of brands is Jawbone? If it's not exclusive, can i have more choices of the brands? By visiting the website, it's stated that "Jawbone ICON" is the switcher for switching connection of devices, right? if not possible listen from 2 sources at once, i know it is complement of switching connection, also more efficient than an old way that disconnect current connection then connect to the other one